# Replacing column of comma separated strings of IDs with values stored in another field based on those IDs using QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I have a layer with three columns:

1. geoid: ID of each polygon (string)
2. totpop: Total population of each polygon (integer)
3. neigh6: Comma separated list of the IDs of polygons that neighbor that polygon (string)

[image: screenshot of attribute table]

So for example, instead of a column with these geoids:
49047940201, 49013940600, 49013940500

I want a column with population for each of those GEOIDs listed:
5039, 6893, 1094

I want to create a new field that has the population of the tract instead of the ID of that tract, eventually to sum up and identify the average population of the neighboring tracts.

I was trying to figure it out with the array_foreach() function, but got stuck. This doesn't work,  (results in all null values), but I wasn't expecting it to since it doesn't account for the specific GEOID.

```
array_foreach(
    string_to_array("neigh6", ','),
        @element="TOTPOP")
```

[image: attempt]

Answer (score 2):

For this I would recommend using a `Virtual Layer` (`Database` --> `DB Manager` --> `Virtual Layers` --> `Project layers`).
Then you can write a `SQL Statement` where you want to join your data on itself and use [aggregate functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html) (QGIS supports the [SQLite](https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/virtual_layers.html#supported-language) SQL syntax in virtual layers). For the `ON` part of the `LEFT JOIN` a `LIKE` between the `neigh6` in `t1` and the `GEOID` in `t2` is used. Before and after the value a `,` is added so we have an unique match.

The query would look like (small modification form [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72619498/how-to-aggregate-two-tables-on-a-comma-separated-string-field)) - You will need to replace `sampleDataAgg` with the name of your current layer:

```sql
SELECT 
    t1.*,
    GROUP_CONCAT(t2.TOTPOP, ',') as "GROUPED NEIGH6 TOTPOP",
    AVG(t2.TOTPOP) as "AVERAGE NEIGH6 TOTPOP"
FROM 
   sampleDataAgg as t1 LEFT JOIN sampleDataAgg as t2 
ON ',' || t1.neigh6 || ',' LIKE '%,' || t2.GEOID || ',%'
GROUP BY t1.GEOID;
```

Then you can load the virtual new layer using `Load as new layer`. If you want to work with the data later it is recommended to export the virtual layer.
[image]

**EDIT:**
After looking at your sample for a second time I think you will need to slightly modify the `ON` part of the `LEFT JOIN` like:

```SQL
ON ', ' || t1.neigh6 || ',' LIKE '%, ' || t2.GEOID || ',%'
```

So it also takes into account that there is an extra space after the comma.

Answer (score 1):

You expression is a good start, but you need to do some more stuff. Explanation as comments in the expression:

```sql
array_to_string( -- turn the result into a string
 array_foreach( -- do the below stuff for each GEOID in neigh6 field
  string_to_array("neigh6",','), -- 1. step: turn the string of ids into an array of ids
   attribute( -- 4. step; see below
    get_feature(@layer,'GEOID', -- 3. step: get the feature with this GEOID
     to_int(@element) -- 2. step: turn each id of the array into an integer. DO NOT DO THIS IF YOUR IDS ARE STRINGS! If so, simply use @element here.
    )
    ,'TOTPOP') -- 4. step: read the attribute "TOTPOP" from the feature
 )
)
```

Be aware of the datatypes! If you use `array_to_string()` or `string_to_array()` all values will always be of type string! If they are integers, doubles or other types, you need to cast them to that type first!

*Just for completness: of course your GEOID's must be unique, otherwise the expression will pick the first result.*