# QGIS How can I transfer atributes from one layer to another when those layers do not share the same number of features?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, attribute-joins

I am trying to add the most populated towns within a number of regions as an attribute to those regions. IE, I want a column on the polygon sheet listing the most populated town in that polygon.

I followed instructions I found via google and was able to make an attribute on the town's point layer which either reads "N/A" or the name of a region if that town is that region's highest populated town. This was achieved using zonal statistics via the town layer's population attribute.

The problem is I have no idea how to take this data and transfer it to the polygon layer. This is my first GIS project of any kind, so I would prefer answers that don't skip steps or abstract parts of the workflow.

Comment: The top 5, 10, ? towns?

Comment: You are looking for "spatial joins" - see: http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_spatial_joins.html

Comment: @BerndLoigge Thank you, but how do I set it up? I don't have a list of matched features I can use like IDs. I have everything as strings though.

Comment: @BERA Just the number 1. IE every polygon should have an attribute with the name of a point with the highest attribute value in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this I would recommend using a `Virtual Layer` (`Database` --> `DB Manager` --> `Virtual Layers` --> `Project layers`). Assume you have a layer cities and a layer regions. First you want to find the city with the highest population (inner query). Then you want to join the cities on the regions using `st_within` and group it by some unique value of the regions layer - in the sample I am using `regions.NAME`. QGIS supports the [SQLite](https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/virtual_layers.html#supported-language) SQL syntax in virtual layers

```sql
select
    *
from
    (
        select name, population, geometry
        from( 
         select 
            name, 
            population,
            geometry,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY population desc)
          as rn
          from cities 
        ) as a
        where rn = 1
    ) as cities,
    regions
where 
    st_within(cities.geometry, regions.geometry)
group by
    regions."NAME"
```

Then you can load the virtual new layer using `Load as new layer`. If you want to work with the data later it is recommended to export the virtual layer.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do my best to figure this one out!

Comment: Have also a look on a similar answer from me: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/436687/replacing-column-of-comma-separated-strings-of-ids-with-values-stored-in-another - you will find some screenshots there.